# If statement gives "[: too many arguments" when grep pattern is found

Tags: bash, if-statement, fedora

I'm trying to make a bash script where it searches for a pattern in different files (they start all with the same word).

The script works but gives an error when the pattern is found ("[: too many arguments") and after the error it gives the result that I'm looking for.
When the pattern is not found, the error does not show up. So how do I get rid of the error when the pattern is found?

```
#!/bin/bash

#Look for sample with their barcode

echo "Wich sample are you looking for?"
read barcode

pattern=$(grep $barcode samples*)

if [ -z $pattern ]

then echo "$barcode did not yet arrive."
else echo "$pattern"

fi
```

Comment: Quotes matter. `[ -z "$pattern" ]` -- also, `grep "$barcode" samples*`

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing issues it identifies before asking questions here.

Comment: thanks, did not know about that site. still new to programming

Comment: It's also a tool you can install on your own machine, not just a website.

Comment: Since you're using `bash`, use `[[` ... `]]` and you don't need to quote the variable: `if [[ -z $pattern ]]`